# replace/rename directory name using regex

Tags: terminal, regex, rename, find-and-replace

i have multiple folder with this pattern "720p.MP4-ABC[abcde]" trying to replace or rename "720p.MP4-CAB[aedcb]" to "."

Comment: What do you want to see as the result in this particular case?

Comment: let say "example.720p.MP4-ABC[abcde]"  is the file name want to rename to "example."

Comment: What operating system / shell?

Comment: im trying to do it on linux

Answer (score 0):

```
echo mv \""NAME"\" \""$(sed -Ee 'regex' <<< "NAME")"\"
```

This will be renaming with using regex.

In your case you may just do:

```
mv "example.720p.MP4-ABC[abcde]" "`sed 's/example\..*//' <<< "example.720p.MP4-ABC[abcde]"`"
```

Comment: but "ABC[abcde]" might change to something else

Comment: @StevenAdward, I am trying to understand what you need, but it's like the fog of mystery sometimes. Could you express yourself as clear as possible with more particular examples? see my edit.

Comment: here two example  Men.In.Black.3.2012.720p.MP4-KTR[rarbg]  and Maleficent.2014.720p.MP4-KTR[rarbg] so i want to rename folder name to Men.In.Black.3.2012  and Maleficent.2014

Comment: `for i in "Men.In.Black.3.2012.720p.MP4-KTR[rarbg]" "Maleficent.2014.720p.MP4-KTR[rarbg]"; do echo mv "'$i'" "'$(echo "$i" | sed -E 's/\.[0-9]{3,4}p.*//')"; done` I think this will work for 720p and 1080p.

Comment: root@Ubuntu-1404-trusty-64-minimal ~/8.20/3 # bash 1.sh
mv 'Men.In.Black.3.2012.720p.MP4-KTR[rarbg]' 'Men.In.Black.3.2012
mv 'Maleficent.2014.720p.MP4-KTR[rarbg]' 'Maleficent.2014
    and is it possible to use wildcard for finding folder name

Comment: @StevenAdward `for i in "Men.In.Black.3.2012.720p.MP4-KTR[rarbg]" "Maleficent.2014.720p.MP4-KTR[rarbg]"; do echo mv "'$i'" "'$(echo "$i" | sed -E 's/\.[0-9]{3,4}p.*//')'"; done` output `mv 'Men.In.Black.3.2012.720p.MP4-KTR[rarbg]' 'Men.In.Black.3.2012'
mv 'Maleficent.2014.720p.MP4-KTR[rarbg]' 'Maleficent.2014'` works in `bash` and `zsh` both

Comment: root@Ubuntu-1404-trusty-64-minimal ~/8.20/3 # bash 1.sh
mv 'Men.In.Black.3.2012.720p.MP4-KTR[rarbg]' 'Men.In.Black.3.2012
mv 'Maleficent.2014.720p.MP4-KTR[rarbg]' 'Maleficent.2014              but nothing changed  and is it possible to use wildcard for finding folder name

Comment: @StevenAdward Exactly. You forgot to stream that to `bash`. Place `| bash` before `;done`